# Chrome Dev Tools not showing request URL after hash # (aka fragment)

Tags: google-chrome, url, google-chrome-devtools

I am doing some debugging and would like to see the full URLs in developer tools, but I could not find a way for that.

Therefore I would like to know:

- Is there a way to achieve it? If not, then how do I deal with it?
- Why Chrome by default is not showing this info? I don't think it could be a security issue, as Chrome is displaying all other sensitive info.

Example:
When I go to `https://stackoverflow.com/abc#qwerty`:

[image]

This is what I see in the network tab:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you see in the dev tools are the request that are sent to the server. What’s behind the # is actually not sent to the server, it’s used by SPA (single page application) to keep track of the state between pages

Comment: Good point, actually. But I would still like to see the full URL somewhere in the debug tools!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Firefox for this case, their Dev Tools show the full URI including the fragment identifier after the hash sign.

Alternatively, you can view it in JS console using location.hash property:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE193.png)

Comment: `location.hash` is not specific to a browser, but rather to a js engine. [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) claims that all browsers support it. Nevertheless, this doesn't help in my case, because some pages on load do an immediate redirect and you don't have enough time to manually run `location.hash`